# Unable to build yaml-cpp in Windows using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, yaml-cpp

I'm trying to build yaml-cpp in Windows 10 using Qt Creator with the MinGW 64-bit kit. I'm using the yaml-cpp-master repository, incase anyone is wondering.

When I try to build it in Qt Creator, I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.16\Modules\CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12: error: sh.exe was found in your PATH, here: C:/devkitPro/msys/bin/sh.exe For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path. Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH. If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles. CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

I also tried the same thing in Qt Creator using Windows Sandbox (to simulate a fresh Windows install), and these errors occur:

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Documents\yaml-cpp-master\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc:637: error: 'AutoHandle' does not name a type; did you mean 'LocalHandle'?
   AutoHandle write_handle_;
   ^~~~~~~~~~
   LocalHandle
```

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Documents\yaml-cpp-master\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:1782: error: 'AutoHandle' does not name a type; did you mean 'mutable'?
   AutoHandle thread_;
   ^~~~~~~~~~
   mutable
```

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Documents\yaml-cpp-master\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc:656: error: 'child_handle_' was not declared in this scope
   const HANDLE wait_handles[2] = { child_handle_.Get(), event_handle_.Get() };
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Documents\yaml-cpp-master\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc:670: error: 'write_handle_' was not declared in this scope
   write_handle_.Reset();
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Documents\yaml-cpp-master\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc:720: error: 'write_handle_' was not declared in this scope
   write_handle_.Reset(write_handle);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Documents\yaml-cpp-master\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\src\gtest-death-test.cc:777: error: 'child_handle_' was not declared in this scope
   child_handle_.Reset(process_info.hProcess);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There's just so many of these errors when done in Windows Sandbox that I can't list them all, there's about 33 of them (with some as duplicates of the same errors). It doesn't occur when I build yaml-cpp in Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux distro and builds almost perfectly without any problems.

So why does these errors only occur in Windows and not in Ubuntu?

When I tried to build yaml-cpp in Qt Creator using the MSVC 2017 64bit kit, this error occurred:

```
C:\Temp\AME\yaml-cpp\test\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-port.h:996: error: C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
```

I'm really confused as to what is going on, and why it only works in GNU/Linux distros, and why it fails to build in Windows? Is there any way to build yaml-cpp in Windows using Qt Creator?

Comment: There are instructions on the Github site for [building](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp#how-to-build) this repository on Windows. Did you follow these instructions? What were the CMake commands you used for each attempt to build?

Comment: @squareskittles There's no instructions on how to build using Qt Creator, only instructions on using CMake and Visual Studio. Does this mean that it can't be built in Qt Creator in Windows? Or is there some specific settings that I have to change (such as CMake commands)? It was able to be built in Ubuntu using Qt Creator though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I've fixed the problem!

All I needed to do was remove `C:/devkitPro/msys/bin/` from the System PATH in Environmental Variables and then disabled **YAML_CPP_BUILD_TESTS** in the Qt Projects Build Settings for yaml-cpp, and it worked!

For some reason, GTest (Google Test Framework) doesn't build in MinGW, that's why it has that error.